# C++ multiple definition of struct functions

Tags: c++, function, header, definition

Sorry for the noob question..

> devf.h

```
#ifndef DEVF_H
#define DEVF_H

#include <string>

struct A {
    int ax();
    std::string ay(std::string jj);
};

struct B {
    struct A* f;            

    int bx() {
        return f->ax();
    }

    std::string by(std::string jj){
        return f->ay(jj);
    }        
};

#endif // DEVF_H
```

> devf.cpp

```
#include "devf.h"

int A::ax() {
    return 5;
}

std::string A::ay(std::string jj){
    return jj;
}
```

I get this error:

```
multiple definition of `A::ax()'

multiple definition of `A::ay(std::string)'
```

How can I solve this problem?  I want the definitions of `ax` and `ay` functions in header file and the implementions in `.cpp`

Comment: I can't reproduce... is there more code?

Comment: Have you used include guards? Something like `#ifndef DEVF_H / #define DEVFH / ... your code ... #endif`

Comment: In your example of `devf.cpp` you have `#include "cni.h"` but where is `#include "devf.h"`?

Comment: I also noticed that in `devf.h` you are including `<iostream>` that doesn't appear to be needed and that you are not including `<string>`...

Comment: OHH! Sorry i will update the question,  yes the code has  #ifndef DEVF_H / #define DEVFH /

Comment: What you show is correct, so the problem is in something you didn't show. What's the command you use to compile this?

Comment: I get a Runtime Error, when i call by or bx function

Comment: Don't tell me that `f` points to an invalid memory address.

Comment: No, the error is specific

Comment: I believe the OP is a victim of `Circular Includes` which will result in multiple definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this with your code:

**devf.h**

```
#ifndef DEVF_H  // Add this line
#define DEVF_H  // Add this line

// #include <iostream> // removed this as not needed from what is shown
#include <string> // added this as is needed

struct A {    
    int ax() const; // added const as it doesn't change
    std::string ay( const std::string& jj ) const; // changed string to const ref & added const  
};

struct B {
    /*struct*/ A* f; // keyword struct not needed here.

    int bx() const { // added const
        return f->ax();
    }

    std::string by( const std::string& jj ) const { // changed to const ref & added const
        return f->ay( jj );
    }        
};

#endif // !DEVF_H  // Add this line
```

**devf.cpp**

```
#include "devf.h"

int A::ax() const {
    return 5;
}

std::string A::ay( const std::string& jj ) const {
    return jj;
}
```

---

Then you asked this or made this statement:

> How can I solve this problem? I want the definitions of ax and ay functions in header file and the implementions in .cpp

---

**devf.h**

```
#ifndef DEVF_H 
#define DEVF_H

#include <string>

struct A {    
    int ax() const;
    std::string ay( const std::string& jj ) const;    
};

struct B {
   A* f;

   int bx() const;     
   std::string by( const std::string& jj ) const; 
};

#endif // !DEVF_H
```

**devf.cpp**

```
#include "devf.h"

int A::ax() const {
    return 5;
}

std::string A::ay( const std::string& jj ) const {
    return jj;
}

int B::bx() const {
    return f->ax();
}

std::string B::by( const std::string& ) const { 
    return f->ay( jj );
}
```

This should help from what you have shown.

---

I've tried it with this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "devf.h"

int main() {

    B b;
    std::cout << b.bx() << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.by( "hello world" ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char q;
    std::cin >> q;
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
5
hello world

Press any key and enter to quit.
```

---

- **EDIT**

I asked the OP: Are you including other header files?

The OP answered with:

> Yes, the header "devf.h" is included in other headers

And I believe this is where the OP's problem resides. I believe that the OP is a victim of `Circular Includes` which will result in multiple definitions.

---

Example:

**A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "B.h" // circular include

struct A {
    int a;
    B b;
};

#endif  // !A_H
```

**B.h**

```
 #ifndef B_H
 #define B_H

 #include "A.h" // circular include

 struct B {
     int b;
 };

 #endif // !B_H
```

---

*To resolve this circular include problem...*

- You need to use `class` or `struct prototypes` - `forward declarations` in the headers; works with `pointer & reference types`.
- Only include other header files within a header file if the `definition` not the `declaration` is needed.
- Once you have the `class` or `struct's forward declaration` in the header file
  remove that `class's` `include directive` and put it within its cpp file

---

*fixing the above example:*

**A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

// Since A has a pointer to B we remove the include from here
// and replace it with a forward declaration or class prototype...
// #include "b.h" // cicular include
class B;
struct A {
    int a;
    B b;
};

#endif // !A_H
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h" // moved the include to here - prevents circular includes
```

**B.h**

```
 #ifndef B_H
 #define B_H

 // Since B does not require A we can omit this all together.
 //#include "A.h" // circular include

 struct B {
     int b;
 };

 #endif // !B_H
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"
```

---

You can refer to this `Q & A` [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes) on stack for a more detailed explanation.

---

Once you go through the rest of your code base and fix all of the circular includes you should have no error as the above set of classes do compile and run without error.

Comment: The problem still exists.

Comment: with "const" in cpp

Comment: @LeAdErQ Are you including other header files?

Comment: Yes, the header "devf.h" is included  in other headers.

Comment: @LeAdErQ I've updated my answer to reflect on your answer to my last question in the comments about the includes... check out the updated answer to see if it helps you to resolve your issue(s).

Comment: The other files just include the devf.h header. I can't understand why this is circular problem.

Comment: @ Yes; and when you include header files in multiple locations that happen to be in other header files you end up getting the run-around which can and probably will result in `multiple definitions`.

Comment: @LeAdErQ I edited again with a link to another `Q & A` from here on stack that has more detailed information about circular dependencies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer!